# Why does my Content Security Policy work everywhere but Safari

Tags: web, safari, content-security-policy

I have defined my security policy as:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

(I still have CSS at the head of several pages).

I have no trouble with Firefox or Chrome (IE doesn't support CSP yet) but, when I try testing in Safari, I get a string of errors like:

```
Refused to load style from 'http://localhost/styles/alliance.css' because of Content-Security-Policy.
.
.
.
Refused to load image from 'http://localhost/images/Landing1.jpg' because of Content-Security-Policy.
.
.
.
Refused to load script from 'http://localhost/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

The images should be covered by default-src and the other two are listed as "Self" so I don't know why Safari is not accepting my images and scripts.  I do not have a Mac so I am using Safari on Windows (5.1.7).

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari 5 is a bit behind in its implementation of CSP. Safari 6 is much better, but I don't think its been released for Windows. I think you're simply seeing implementation bugs. If WebKit nightlies are available for Windows, that might be a good alternative for testing.

Honestly, though, I wouldn't recommend serving the `X-WebKit-CSP` header to Safari 5. Safari 6, yes, but 5 is a bit too broken to really use.

Note also that you can simplify your policy. Both `script-src` and `frame-src` will fall back to `default-src`. `default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` should have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I had seen references to how Safari 6 implemented CSP and the absence of commentary to the same effect for Safari 5 had me wondering.  Given the dearth of Windows users of Safari I am inclined to ignore it but it still helps to know that they are the problem rather than me.

Comment: Thanks for your other observations as well.  The "extra" pieces were vestigial; I had originally not provided default-src and Chrome worked fine. Firefox, however, required it.

Comment: Firefox has a little bit of work to do before they're completely compliant with the 1.0 spec, but they're making rapid progress. I expect they'll be supporting the unprefixed `Content-Security-Policy` header Soon™, which will make things a little easier for you. (Chrome should support the unprefixed header in 25).

Comment: @MikeWest: Is there any way to support for IE11. I tried with res.setHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "sandbox 'allow-same-origin'"); and many other things for IE11. But nothing working. Anythng to work around for IE11 ?