# Content Security Policy [Error] Refused to load the script safari

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

I am behind with CSP, this morning all sites on one of my servers stopped working with safari with the following error:

> [Error] Refused to load the script
>   'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

How can I fix this server-wide without having to change each sites 1 by 1.

As mentionned I am a bit behind with CSP, as such I don't even know where to put the rules

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Content Security Policy work everywhere but Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663302/why-does-my-content-security-policy-work-everywhere-but-safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, here's what I had done 'incorrectly'.

in the file /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf

I placed a bunch of default headers to secure the server including:

```
Header set X-WebKit-CSP: "default-src 'self'"
```

Which caused Safari to refuse any script not hosted on localhost.

The confusion came because nobody found the problem before a week after the fact.

Comment: `X-WebKit-CSP` is outdated. You probably want `Content-Security-Policy`. Look at the following URL for current browser support: http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: So what is the actual solution? How can you get it to work on Safari and keep using the CSP headers?